# Jasmine tests to handle promise and $q.when

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

This is localeDataService to retrieve some data.

```
function getapplicableitems() {
    if (profile.region === 'ASIA') {
        return otherDataService.getOtherData()
            .then(function(data) {
                return data;
            });
        }
    return $q.when(false);
}
```

These are my below jasmine tests.

```
describe('Locale Data Service Tests:',
function() {

    var sut,
        profile = {},
        otherDataServiceMock = {},
        $q;

    beforeEach(module(function($provide) {
        otherDataServiceMock = {
            getOtherData: function() {}
        };

        spyOn(otherDataServiceMock, 'getOtherData')
            .and.callFake(function() {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                deferred.resolve('Remote call result');
                return deferred.promise;
            });

        $provide.value('profile', profile);
        $provide.value('otherDataService', otherDataServiceMock);
    }));

    beforeEach(inject(function(_localeDataService_, _$q_) {
        $q = _$q_;
        sut = _localeDataService_;
    }));

    it('should not call if region is NOT ASIA', function() {
            profile.region = 'ZZZZ';

            spyOn(otherDataServiceMock, 'getOtherData').andReturn($q.when(false));

            sut.getOtherData();

          expect(otherDataServiceMock.getOtherData).toEqual($q.when(false));

    });

    it('should call for ASIA', function() {
            profile.region = 'ASIA';

            sut.getOtherData();

            expect(otherDataServiceMock.getOtherData).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
});
```

I am not able to get this "should not call if region is NOT ASIA" test to work. I am new to jasmine/unit testing. Please help.

Comment: where is your getapplicableitems function used

Comment: localeDataService.getapplicableitems()
                    .then(function(data) {
                        $scope.items = data;
                    });

Comment: its used like in controller which is shared for multiple locations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I resolved it. There was no point calling otherDataServiceMock as it is not used when the region is ZZZZ.

```
it('should not call if region is NOT ASIA', function() {
        profile.region = 'ZZZZ';
        var noChange = true;

        sut.getOtherData().then(function(){
           noChange = false;
        });

      expect(noChange).toBeTruthy()

});
```